# Where/Having on an aggregate function issue

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I am writing a query:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  count , var1, var2
FROM  table 
GROUP BY var1, var2
ORDER BY  count DESC
```

This query works but it grabs everything.  I am trying to only get results where count > x (any arbitrary number).

I have tried using `WHERE count > x` and get:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'Spammers' in 'where clause'

If I use `HAVING count > x` (Added it at the very end) I get:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Other details: using Mysql 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HAVING count(*) > x`

Where `x` is an integer.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  count , var1, var2
FROM  table 
GROUP BY var1, var2
ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
Having count(*) > x
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I had tried this before but I must have mis-read the documentation, it suggested HAVING should be at the end unless you've got a LIMIT statement.  Apparently ORDER BY also goes before it.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
WHERE count(*) > x
```

You cant use an alias in a WHERE clause.

You can also use:

```
HAVING count(*) > x
```